# Get outuput of wp_head or wp_footer in wordpress Rest API

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is there a way to get what come with **wp_head()** or **wp_footer()** in rest api call?

I mean scripts and styles that can come from plugin or WordPress itself when I use **wp_enqueue_script** for example?

The reason is that I want to make everything with js framework, but I want to save the extendable by the plugins (not with all but if it's for styling for example that gives only special style).

If it's impossible so it would be good to know *why*...?

Also, if there is a way to circumvent this it also would be helpful in future.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not...And just don't work with WP anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a custom API endpoint which contains the code for the header or footer. Then on whatever you're consuming the API with you'd have to parse and execute that code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a custom REST endpoint and place all scripts/styles output there. Also you can place a custom logic there if you have a different output depending on post type/taxonomy/etc.

You can also modify output of existing endpoints by using some filters, e.g.

```
apply_filters( "rest_prepare_{$this->post_type}", $response, $post, $request );
```